# How to .replace an encodedURLcomponent on javascript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

So basically when I run this function, if I have `?element=value&element1=value2` attached at the end of the url, I can input the data in the element field on the website.

But if I add a space, ex: `element=value+value2`. the space is transposed on the field instead of identifying it as a space.

I have tried using `%20` which will convert it to + and i have tried to do `.replace` in many places and it just doesn't do it

```
javascript: function getUrlVars() {
var vars = [],
hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
function ParamsIntoForms(get) {
    for (var i = 0; i < get.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByName(get[i]).length != 0) {
            document.getElementsByName(get[i])[0].value = decodeURIComponent(get[get[i]]);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
var get = getUrlVars();
ParamsIntoForms(get);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function getUrlVars () {
    const searchString = window.location.search.substr(1);
    const paramPairs = searchString.split('&');
    const keyValues = {};
    paramPairs.forEach(paramPair => {
        const pair = paramPair.split('=');
        // You need to replace the + signs you are using as spaces with %20, which can be decoded properly.
        keyValues[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
    })
    return keyValues;
}

function praseIntoForms(keyValues) {
    Object.keys(keyValues).forEach(key => {
        if (document.getElementsByName(key).length != 0) {
            // Only replaces the first element of this name, is this what you want?
            document.getElementsByName(key)[0].value = keyValues[key];
        }
    });
}

const urlValues = getUrlVars();
praseIntoForms(urlValues);
```

Although I don't really understand why you are doing what you are doing.

Comment: Doesn’t work.
Lemme give an example.
 So say you have a url.
www.youtube.com right, so if you inspect element on the webpage and the name of the search bar the name is “search_bar” or whatever it is right
So if you do this www.youtube.com?search_bar= Hello
And then run the bookmarklet, it would auto fill the field. Now say you want to add a space, the url would look like this:
www.youtube.com?search_bar= Hello+world
But in the search bar it looks like Hello+ world instead of Hello world. 
Try it for yourself. Copy the code and bookmark it and put the code where the url would go